# System of Linear Eq solution using inverse matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

My question is about solving a system of equations using an inverse matrix.  I'm confused with a condition where both equations are set equal to zero, such that the roots can be solved.  In this case it seems the results are only the trivial solutions of $0$.  Am I going about this correctly?

For instance if:

$$a_{11} x_1 + a_{12} x_2 = 0$$
$$a_{21} x_1 + a_{22} x_2 = 0$$

such that:
$$A =\begin{bmatrix}
    a_{11} & a_{12} \\
    a_{21} & a_{22} \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$
$$
\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
    x_1 \\ x_2 \end{bmatrix}, \mathbf b = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

and

$$A \mathbf x = \mathbf b, det(A) \ne 0$$

$$A^{-1} A \mathbf x = A^{-1} \mathbf b$$

$$\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks great, assuming you are using say the real numbers or the complex numbers, or maybe even any field. You have what is called a homogeneous system of linear equations. If the matrix of coefficients is invertible, the system has only the trivial solution.

Comment: Thanks.  I graphed for instance $x + y = 0, 4x + 2y = 0$ and noted that the lines intersect at $x=0, y=0$.  I also modified the coefficients and had the same results at $(0,0)$.  So this appears to agree.  Finally, what is the next step if the $A$ is not invertible (i.e. $det(A) = 0$ linearly dependence)?

Comment: this seems to show some nice pictures and several examples. I'd study this if I were you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination